# React Native - Border style looks different on Android than iOS

Tags: android, css, react-native

I'm building an app using react native. A lot of my elements have this css:

```
style: {
    display: 'flex',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.12,
    shadowRadius: 5.46,
    elevation: 9,
},
```

Below are links of the same screens and how the borders look:

iOS:
https://ibb.co/YZrC0GB ,
https://ibb.co/bzJR1N4

Android:
https://ibb.co/5xShkMv ,
https://ibb.co/WHWMn5x

As you can see it looks great on iOS but not sure what behavior is causing it to look different.

Any ideas how I can change the css to look better in Android using something like this `Platform.OS === "android"` :

```
style: {
    display: 'flex',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: Platform.OS === "android" ? 2 : 10, //Something like this
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 4,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.12,
    shadowRadius: 5.46,
    elevation: 9,
},
```

Comment: do you mean the problem are with the shadows?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what the problem is on Android. At first glance it looks OK.

Comment: @AkinoArchilles yes the problem is with the shadows. if you look at the second link i sent that says barber, make up artist. If you look at the shadow behind the element its thicker and darker.

Comment: @AHaworth it's the shadow I'm referring to. If you look at the images again you will notice the shadow is different.

Comment: on Android shadows can only be controlled with elevation and nothing else, if you're looking to customize shadow in Android, there's no workaround. try to make it at least "acceptable" @JImmyG